# Is the Euclidean vector a tensor?

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

A rank $(1,0)$ tensor is a map $V^{\ast} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, where $V^{\ast}$ is the dual space of a module $V$ defined over $\mathbb{K}$.

How does this relate to the standard "high-school" Euclidean vector? i.e. let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$. A Euclidean vector could then be expressed (by a chart) in terms of a 2-tuple of numbers $(a,b)$. How does this relate back to the abstract definition of a $(1,0)$-tensor?

Comment: Assuming $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, a module over $\mathbb{K}$ is just a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're identifying $V$ with $V^{\ast\ast}$, which is always possible if $\dim V < +\infty$. We look at $\hat{v} \in V^{\ast \ast}$ acting as $\hat{v}(\phi) \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \phi(v)$, where $\phi \in V^\ast$. Then we say that "$\hat{v} = v$" and there you go: $v$ is acting as a $(1,0)-$tensor.

In smooth manifolds, a tangent vector $v \in T_pM$ can act in functions $f \in C^\infty(M)$ by $v(f) \stackrel{\cdot}{=} {\rm d}f_p(v)$, and this sort of behaves like above. You can take $M = \Bbb R^2$ and $v = (a,b)$ in a chart, for concreteness - it is a directional derivative.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer.
I think my problem is the notation. If $v=(a,b)$, i.e. a 2-tuple, where $a : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $b : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are components, how is v a map from $V^{\ast} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Would it not be a map $V^{\ast} \times V^{\ast} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2$, since there are two components? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: If $f \in (\Bbb R^2)^\ast$, there are constants $c_f,d_f \in \Bbb R$ such that $f((x,y)) = c_fx+d_fy$, for all $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$. Note my extra parentheses. We say that $(a,b)(f) = c_fa+d_fb$, and this is linear in $f$. Since $v$ is only a vector, and not a vector field, $a$ and $b$ are not functions, but constants. Writing it as a $2-$tuple is a peculiarity of the vector space $\Bbb R^2$, you can't do this in other vector spaces without making use of some isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

A general tensor of type $(p, q)$ is a section of the bundle $TX^{\otimes p} \otimes T^*X^{\otimes q}$ over a (smooth, etc.) manifold $X$. Since Euclidean space is contractible, the bundles $TX$ and $T^*X$ are contractible, and a $(p, q)$-tensor over it just the same as a map to $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$. In more direct terms, there's a convenient translation map between the fibers of this bundle at any two points, which means we can identify an element of a general fiber with an element of $T_0X^{\otimes p}\otimes T_0^*X^{\otimes q} = \mathbb{R}^{p+q}$. This is not the case on a general manifold; we can try to identify fibers via parallel transport, local triviality, etc., but we can't globally identify fibers because the tangent bundle is not necessarily trivial.